# How to print a vector in a sentence avoiding returning lines

Tags: r, vector, printf, cat

I want to print values from a vector in a sentence. But the vector is containing 4 elements, which is causing the answer to be spread across 4 lines. This is what I have:

```
  yo = c(2902, 2908, 2907, 2918)

  cat(paste('You have', yo, 'number of individuals per species\n', sep = ' '))

 You have 2902 number of individuals per species
 You have 2908 number of individuals per species
 You have 2907 number of individuals per species
 You have 2918 number of individuals per species
```

But I want something like this

```
You have 2902, 2908, 2907 and 2918 number of individuals per species
```

Is it possible to do this?  Also, the vector will not be always containing 4 elements. If I have only 3 or 10 elements, it should work.

This is not working:

```
  cat(sprintf('You have %s number of individuals per species\n',yo))


  cat(paste('You have', unlist(yo), 'number of individuals per species\n', sep = ' '))
```

Comment: Try `toString(c(yo[-length(yo)], paste("and", yo[length(yo)])))`. This uses the Oxford comma.  I cringe otherwise.

Comment: Thumbs up for the Oxford comma!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `toString()` with `paste()` to get the last part.  I also use an Oxford comma for good measure ...

```
x <- toString(c(yo[-length(yo)], paste("and", yo[length(yo)])))
x
# [1] "2902, 2908, 2907, and 2918"
```

So now we can just insert `x` into the `paste()` call.

```
paste("You have", x, "number of individuals per species")
# [1] "You have 2902, 2908, 2907, and 2918 number of individuals per species"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to `paste()` with `collapse` option :

```
paste('You have',paste( yo[1:(length(yo)-1)], collapse= ', '), 'and', yo[length(yo)], 'number of individuals per species\n')
You have 2902, 2908, 2907 and 2918 number of individuals per species
```

Comment: can you add an "and" before the last value automatically instead of a comma?